# Json ignore field only when a condition

Tags: java, json

I want to ignore a field when a it can be retrieved:

```
public boolean isActiveProduct() {

    ....
    ...
    if (product != null) {
        return product.isActiveProduct();
    }

    // ignore this field and don't return it in reponse
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL) ?

Comment: @Beri thanks but I cant' use it in my case I want to ignore the boolean value when product is null not its value (product.isActiveProduct()) is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another method (possibly less visible) for JSON serialization, which returns `null`, if the product is `null`. Apply these annotations to this new method:

```
@JsonProperty("activeProduct")
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Nullable // optional annotation for static code analyser
protected Boolean isActiveProductOrNull() {
    if (product != null) {
        return product.isActiveProduct();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Tag the current method as `@JsonIgnore`.

```
@JsonIgnore
public boolean isActiveProduct() {
    if (product != null) {
        return product.isActiveProduct();
    } else {
        return false; // or throw an exception, if you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work when product = null it display activeProduct = false! thank u

Comment: Of course it does. I did similar thing multiple times.

Comment: Hello Yes it works an without the second method  annitated with @JsonIgnore.

Comment: It works with and without the seconde method I want to say ;)